# What is the best way to smooth a curve?

Tags: python, data-analysis

I am working on a fitting algorithm that requires a boundary condition of `f(x=0) = 0`. However, let's say my fitting result is a numpy array `y`, if I naively set `y[0]=0`, the curve would look pretty awkward because of a sudden bump from `y[0]` to `y[1]`. I made up something similar to what my final curve looks like:

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

fig, ax = plt.subplots(1,1, figsize=(10,6))

x = np.arange(0,3.5,0.02)
y = 1/(1+(x-1.2)**2) - 0.3
y[0] = 0

ax.plot(x,y)
ax.axhline(color = 'r')
ax.axvline(color = 'r')

plt.show()
```

Below is the plot of the above python code. I am wondering if there is a smarter way to smooth the curve (just like the red line I drew)? I tried `scipy.signal.savgol_filter` but it is not very effective.

In my application, the value near zero is not very important. As long as the whole plot looks smooth and continuous, it would good.

[image]

Edit:

I realized that I might have described the question in a poor way. What I mean is not fitting the relationship I presented in the above code `y = 1/(1+(x-1.2)**2) - 0.3`. I mean there is some functional `F(y(x))`, and I am trying to find `y(x)` such that `F(y(x))` is a minimum (something like a least-square fit). There is an imposed condition for `y(x)`, requiring `y(0) = 0`. However, if I simply enforce `y[0] = 0`, the resultant curve `y(x)` would like awkward near 0. I wonder if there is a way to smooth it.

[image]

Comment: is your data always this consistent? at this point you might as well just chop your data off at t=0.5 and connect a straight line to 0,0

Comment: In general, yes. It should look like a hill just with different peak positions and heights. However, I am running an iterative algorithm. In the first few iterations, the behavior is rather unpredictable. Hardcoding at a fixed range may not be a suitable approach. I guess.

Answer (score 0):

The best way for setting a boundary condition is to force it in your fitting curve definition.

In your case you have your fitting curve written as:

y(x) = 1/(1+(x-a)**2) - b

and I guess you are fitting a and b. The problem is that as long as you leave both a and b to be free you can't impose the boundary condition.

To impose the boundary condition you have to impose:

0 = y(0) = 1/(1+a**2) - b

Which gives you:

b = 1/(1+a**2)

And thus:

y(x) = 1/(1+(x-a)**2) - 1/(1+a**2)

Which of course vanishes for x = 0

Now you just have to fit the parameter "a" to your data.

Comment: Sorry, maybe my question is not clear enough. I am not fitting the equation I am presenting. I am fitting some rather complicated indirect Fourier transform stuff. I mean my final fitting result looks like `1/(1+(x-1.2)**2) - 0.3`. However, I want to smooth the curve so that `f(x)=0`. Let me include a real curve in the question.